# Remove Ads when In-App Billing is successful

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, ads

In my class where I implemented the In-App Billing I have this `onIabPurchaseFinished()` method:

```
@Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {

    if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(info)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_purchasing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.premium_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (info.getSku().equals("chords_premium")) {
        // bought the premium upgrade!
        isPremium = true;

        /** salva isPremium tra SharedPreferences */
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isPremium", isPremium);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

As you can see when the purchase is successful `isPremium` is set to `true` and saved in `SharedPreferences`

What I need to do now is not show AdMob ads when the purchase is successful.

This is an example of how I did it in a class I have implemented Ads in:

```
// I get the boolean from SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences PremiumPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean isPremium = PremiumPref.getBoolean("isPremium", false);
```

and the I manage the ads like this with the `if(!isPremium)`:

```
if (!isPremium) {
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-6723047396589178/2654753246");

        AdView listBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.chords_list_banner);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        listBanner.loadAd(adRequest);

        /** carica Ad a tutto schermo */
        chordsListAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        chordsListAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6723047396589178/7447672046");
        requestNewInterstitial();


        chordsListAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that when **I test it, and buy the Premium upgrade, Ads are still showing!**

As you can see it's not only Banners I need to remove, but also Interstitial Ads

What am I doing wrong? how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

this is the progress I have made:

```
@Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {

    if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(info)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_purchasing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.premium_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (info.getSku().equals("chords_premium")) {
        // bought the premium upgrade!
        isPremium = true;

        /** salva isPremium tra SharedPreferences */
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isPremium", isPremium);
        editor.apply();

        removeAds();
    }
}

public void removeAds() {
    AdView listBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.chords_list_banner);
    listBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    AdView chordBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.chord_banner);
    chordBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    AdView searchBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.search_ad);
    searchBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

as you can see I've added the `removeAds()` method as suggested in the answer. But **how do I remove the Interstitials in this method?**

Answer (score 0):

You should call a method in your `onIabPurchaseFinished`, something like `hideAds`, which would hide your current shown `AdView` with a simple snippet like this:

```
AdView listBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.chords_list_banner);
listBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

EDIT:
Also later on the In-app-billing setting should be checked when the app starts whether the premium is already bought.

Comment: I have read in the documentation that using `View.GONE` for Ads is not recommended, furthermore, it wouldn't be permanent since when the app is closed it will be reset, right? On top of that I have not only banners that have to be gone, but also interstitials

Comment: Well there's a check for in-app billing which should be called every time user opens app, it returns information about whether premium is bought. However as you save the state of the premium in a shared preference you can load it back when the user opens the app next time.

Comment: I will have a look at that, how about interstitials?